# How to redirect if logged in the application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a web site, and right now whether I'm logged or not, when I go to the root it shows my log in form. What I want is that if I'm logged and got to `/` redirect to `/api/admin`

Here is what my route config looks like:

```
const routes = {
  path: '/',
  component: App;
  indexRoute: { component: Login },
  childRoutes: [
     { path: 'twitter', component: TwitterIn },
  ]
}
```

My question is how can I put some login here, something like

```
 if (UserLogged) {
     //goto /api/admin
 } else {
    //behave just like is behaving now
 }
```

Comment: Which version of react-router are you using?

Comment: 3.2.1. I'm also using react-router-redux: 4.0.7

Answer (score 1):

If you are using React-Router, wrap your default exported component using [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter). You can import it using:

```js
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
```

And when you are using the default export, you can do this way:

```js
const Comp extends React.Component {
  // ...
}
export default withRouter(Comp);
```

The `withRouter` higher-order component will pass updated `match`, `location`, and `history` props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

And in the constructor or wherever you are checking for the condition, you can use `this.props.history` and redirect this way:

```js
if (UserLogged) {
  // goto /api/admin
  this.props.history.replace("/api/admin");
}
```

If that's not possible, you can use the [`<Redirect />`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Redirect) API, which can be imported this way:

```js
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router';
```

This works only if you are inside the render function (I guess).

```js
render() {
  if (UserLogged) {
    // goto /api/admin
    return <Redirect to="/api/admin" />;
  }  
  return (
    <p>Your usual HTML</p>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was looking to add something in the indexRoute inside routes

Comment: @danielcobra Ah okay! 

Comment: @danielcobra Did you get a solution for your question? Can I help you further?  Just thought of asking if it got solved, you can post your answer, if not I can try again.

Answer (score 0):

In my last project, I defined all the routing within a React Component. Within that Component, 'user' was defined as a state property set to either 'null' (logged out) or a valid user object (logged in). The Component's rendering logic then returned one set of routes (redirecting to the login page) if the user was logged out and a different set of routes (full application routes) if the user was logged in.